# smartparens NOT insert pair of LaTeX quotes?

Tags: latex, smartparens

**Q:** how do I get `smartparens` *not* to insert a pair of ``LaTeX'' quotes?

#### The goal

I set up `smartparens` to insert a pair of quotation marks
*unless* point is just before a word or just after it, where `*`
is point:

```
some text * some more text ==> some text "*" some more text
*some text                 ==> "*some text
some text*                 ==> some text"*
```

I have it set up for `text-mode` and `org-mode` like so:

```
(sp-local-pair '(text-mode org-mode) "\"" nil
               :unless '(sp-point-before-word-p
                         sp-point-after-word-p))
```

#### The problem

LaTeX is goofy with ``double quotes'' and `single quotes'.  That is: double quotes are done with *two* backticks on the front and *two* ticks at the end.  This
doesn't work:

```
(sp-local-pair '(latex-mode) "\"" nil
               :unless '(sp-point-before-word-p
                         sp-point-after-word-p))
```

#### The ugly "solution"

After much tinkering, the following works somewhat:

```
(with-eval-after-load "latex"
  (sp-local-pair '(latex-mode) "`" nil
                 :unless '(sp-point-before-word-p))
  (sp-local-pair '(latex-mode) "'" nil
                 :unless '(sp-point-after-word-p))
  (sp-local-pair '(latex-mode) "``" nil
                 :unless '(sp-point-before-word-p))
  (sp-local-pair '(latex-mode) "''" nil
                 :unless '(sp-point-after-word-p)))
```

But that seems a little ludicrous for such simple functionality.  It's also far from perfect, in that I get new and sometimes baffling errors from `yasnippet`, of all things.

#### The mournful appeal

**Am I missing some simple, LaTeX-specific way of doing this?**

Comment: Sorry, what does "LaTex is goofy" mean? Doesn't work how?

Comment: @Tyler: edited: an opening quote is comprised of *two* backticks, and a closing quote is comprised of *two* ticks (ie, apostrophes).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to eventually achieve: do you want an easy way to insert ``LaTeX'' quotes? Do you use AUCTeX?

Comment: @giordano: yes, I'm using AUCTeX.  [`smartparens`](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) inserts pairs of parentheses, quotes, etc.  When I enter `"`, it gives me a pair of LaTeX quotes.  I want it to do that *except* when point is just before the start of a word (when I want it to insert just the opening quote) or just after the end of a word (when I want it to insert just the closing quote).

Comment: Why not just use `C-q "` in the special situations?

Comment: I don't use nor know smartparens, but AUCTeX is quite smart with regard to quotes.  It's especially useful if you write in languages other than English that have their own special rules about quotes, but if you care only about English you may not be much interested in this feature.  Anyway, `"` in AUCTeX is context-aware, it inserts double backticks if there is nothing before point, and double ticks if point is after a word, in addition in math mode it inserts a literal `"`.

Comment: BTW, also in comments `"` inserts a literal `"`.

Comment: @giordano: thanks, I use AUCTeX daily and am quite fond of it.  The issue is `smartparens`-specific: ordinarily, typing `"` will enter the opening quote, the closing quote, and put point in between them.  I was trying to make `smartparens` smarter by turning that feature off when point was at the beginning or end of a word.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: I think the rendering on this site may be causing some confusion.  I don't want to enter a single standard `"` (eg, with `C-q "`).  I want to enter a single *LaTeX* double quote, which is *two* backquotes one after another (`\`\``), and which LaTeX renders as the opening quote.

Comment: I see.  You asked for a LaTeX-specific solution, so I thought you weren't completely aware of this AUCTeX's feature ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* I have it.  The goal is to get `smartparens` to:

- insert a pair of *``LaTeX quotes''*
- unless at the beginning of a word, when it inserts the
  *``opening quote*
- unless at the end of a word, when it inserts the *closing quote''*

Here's the code:

```
(require 'smartparens-latex)

(sp-local-pair '(tex-mode plain-tex-mode latex-mode LaTeX-mode)
               "``" "''"
               :trigger "\""
               :unless '(sp-latex-point-after-backslash
                         sp-point-before-word-p
                         sp-point-after-word-p)
               :pre-handlers  '(sp-latex-pre-slurp-handler)
               :post-handlers '(sp-latex-skip-double-quote))

(sp-local-pair '(tex-mode plain-tex-mode latex-mode LaTeX-mode)
               "`" "'"
               :trigger "'"
               :unless '(sp-latex-point-after-backslash
                         sp-point-before-word-p
                         sp-point-after-word-p)
               :pre-handlers  '(sp-latex-pre-slurp-handler)
               :post-handlers '(sp-latex-skip-double-quote))
```

Note that this modifies the settings I found when digging around
in the code base
in
[`smartparens-latex`](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/blob/master/smartparens-latex.el).

**NB:** this only seems to work if you redefine the local pair for
*both* the double quotes and the single quotes.  If you do only
the former, this is what you get when trying to insert a double
quote at the beginning of a word:

```
``'gasp, clutch my pearls
```